# how to install postgis 2.2 with PostgreSQL 9.5 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to install Postgis 2.2 with Postgresql 9.5 in ubuntu 18.04 with no success.
I have tried installing the deb package provided in [this link](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/postgresql/bionic-pgdg/main/base/postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.4) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://kitcharoenp.github.io/postgresql/postgis/2018/05/28/set_up_postgreSQL_postgis.html

Comment: @mth1417un That installs v2.4, not 2.2 (which is unnecessary because 2.4 is in the repos). It looks like older versions are only available through SVN.

Comment: @mth1417un that installs Postgresql 10 with Postgis 2.4. I wanted Postgresql 9.5 and Postgis 2.2

Comment: can you provide a bit more details as to what did not work in the link? did you get any error messages ect?

Comment: Installing Postgis complained of some uninstalled dependancies. I tried to install the dependencies but failed. I reinstalled the OS to Ubuntu 16.04 which worked well.